# What am I doing wrong with the PHP-mail?

Tags: php, email

I have been working with html lately, but now I want to send an email with PHP. However, it keeps failing. Does anyone know what I do wrong? I am trying to send al the questions in an email. this is the code:

```
 <?php
   if (!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
   ?>

   <form method="post" action="">
   1. gender:<br>
   <input type="radio" name="question 1" />male<br>
   <input type="radio" name="question 1" />female<br><br>

    2. Age:
    <input type=text name="question 2" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>

    <?php 
     } else {   
    $from = "ownemail@gmail.com"; 
    $subject = "Pesten";
    $message = $_POST["quesion 1; question 2"];
    $message = wordwrap($message, 70);
    mail("email@yourdomain.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
    echo "Thanks for the feedback!";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This `$message = $_POST["quesion 1; question 2"];` that's invalid.

Comment: Where did you read you can access array indexes like this? `$_POST["quesion 1; question 2"];`

Answer (score 2):

This `$message = $_POST["quesion 1; question 2"];` is invalid.

Change it to `$choice=$_POST['question_1'];` while changing both `name="question 1"` to `name="question_1"` then do `$message = $choice;`

Name attributes can't contain spaces, use underscores between both words.

There's also this `<input type=text name="question 2" />` to be changed to
`<input type="text" name="question_2" />` and add `$choice2=$_POST['question_2'];`, then concatenate the `$message` variable(s).

- You also had a one closing brace `}` too many at the end of your code.

**N.B.:** To "concatenate" means to link together using a dot `.` which should be left where they are below. Do not delete them.

---

***Here's a rewrite*** (added `value="male"` and `value="female"` to your radio buttons.

Not doing that, would result in getting back the words `on` instead of their intended values.

```
<?php
   if (!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
?>

<form method="post" action="">
1. Gender:<br>
<input type="radio" name="question_1" value="male" />male<br>
<input type="radio" name="question_1" value="female" />female<br><br>


2. Age:
<input type="text" name="question_2" />

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

<?php 
 } else {  
$from = "ownemail@gmail.com"; 
$subject = "Pesten";
$choice=$_POST['question_1'];
$choice2=$_POST['question_2'];

$choices = $choice . ": " . $choice2;
$message .= wordwrap($choices, 70);
   mail("email@yourdomain.com",$subject,$message,"From: $from\n");
     echo "Thanks for the feedback!";
   }

?>
```

---

**Extra options:**

You can also replace:

```
$choices = $choice . ": " . $choice2;
$message .= wordwrap($choices, 70);
```

with

```
$choices = "Gender: " . $choice . "\n" . "Age: " . $choice2;
$message .= wordwrap($choices, 70);
```

if you wish to show the message to read something like:

Gender: Female
Age: 33

---

If you want to make sure that someone enters a number instead of text for the age field, replace this block:

```
<?php 
 } else {  
$from = "ownemail@gmail.com"; 
$subject = "Pesten";
$choice=$_POST['question_1'];
$choice2=$_POST['question_2'];
```

with and using the [`is_numeric()`](http://www.php.net/is_numeric) function:

```
<?php 
 } else {

if(!is_numeric($_POST['question_2'])){
die("Click back and try again. You must enter a number.");
}

$from = "ownemail@gmail.com"; 
$subject = "Pesten";
$choice=$_POST['question_1'];
$choice2=$_POST['question_2'];
```

Comment: For the intensive detail on the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do like this

```
$message = $_POST["quesion 1; question 2"];
```

This syntax is invalid. And also you cannot give whitespace in field names. You have to use underscores instead of space.

Change this to

```
$message = $_POST["quesion_1"]; 
$message.=$_POST["question_2"];
```

Please read about [$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php).